# RegionPlot3D with additional variables

Tags: plotting, regions

Why doesn't this RegionPlot3D not plot anything?

```
RegionPlot3D[ 0 < Subscript[y, 1] < 1 && Subscript[y, 2] == 0 && Subscript[y, 3] == 1 - Subscript[y, 1] && Subscript[x, 1] == 1 && Subscript[x, 2] == 0 && Subscript[x, 3] == 0, {Subscript[y, 1], 0, 1}, {Subscript[y, 2], 0, 1}, {Subscript[y, 3], 0, 1}]
```

The result I would expect would be this one:

```
RegionPlot3D[ 0 < Subscript[y, 1] < 1 && Subscript[y, 2] == 0 && Subscript[y, 3] == 1 - Subscript[y, 1], {Subscript[y, 1], 0, 1}, {Subscript[y, 2], 0, 1}, {Subscript[y, 3], 0, 1}]
```

I have much more complicated expressions than this, where the common theme is that there will be 3 free variables which I specify where to plot (here, $y_1, y_2, y_3$) and all other variables will be given, like above (e.g., $x_1, x_2, x_3$ here) and I want to plot the resulting region. Is there a correct way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
contrains = 
  0 < y[1] < 1 && y[2] == 0 && y[3] == 1 - y[1] && x[1] == 1 && 
   x[2] == 0 && x[3] == 0;
reg = ParametricRegion[{{y[1], y[2], y[3]}, 
    contrains}, {{y[1], 0, 1}, {y[2], 0, 1}, {y[3], 0, 1}, x[1], x[2],
     x[3]}];
DiscretizeRegion[reg, Boxed -> True]
Region[Style[reg, Thick, Blue], Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there really no way to use RegionPlot3D? I wanted its features, like the labels and all, or other future necessary things. Region seems to be very general, though.

Comment: @Jay    Up to the 12.3.1 version, `RegionPlot3D` still can't draw such equations. We can use label in `Region` or use `Show` to add another objects in such figure.